# execution order of javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am back to the basics, in order to better understand JavaScript. I have a testing website. Here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
test
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function saySomething(message)
{
alert(message);
}

saySomething('Hello world!');

function addLoadListener(fn){
window.addEventListener('load', fn, false);
alert("the previous alert came from onload");
}

addLoadListener(saySomething);


</script>


<body>
<div>blah blah blah</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, there is this function, `saySomething` that alerts `Hello World!`. I add it to `addLoadListener` so it can be called during page loading. And works fine till this part. But after that, gets called again as the code runs and alerts `[object Event]` instead of `Hello World!`. Why? What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Try the fiddle ,everything is ok http://jsfiddle.net/X3vLP/1/

Comment: @PratikJoshi Thanks Patrick, but I dot see another `Hello World!` after the page load. Also it would be nice if you provide an explanation of why this is happening. Thanks

Comment: @PratikJoshi You must change the loading mechanism of jsFiddle from `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <head>`

Comment: As you can see you add your function to event listener without any arguments so why do you expect "Hello World"? Browsers call your function and pass event object it is correct behaviour.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

May be you are missing your argument

```
<html>
 <head>
 test
 </head>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function saySomething(message)
  {
 alert(message);
 }

 saySomething('Hello world!');

function addLoadListener(fn){
  window.addEventListener('load', fn, false);
alert("the previous alert came from onload");
}

 addLoadListener(saySomething('Hello world!'));


 </script>


  <body>
  <div>blah blah blah</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: That's not solving the problem. The function `saySomething` now gets fired immediately and not at the `load` event.

Comment: @Coder Aha! So its the other way around. The function during the `onload` did not work. Makes sense. Thanks. Way to understand the basics. What is wrong with me?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that once you attach the `saySomething` function as an event listener to the load event of the window it is later called with different arguments when the event fires. Actually the argument is an event object, that's why you see `[object Event]` alerted.

While I don't know the real purpose of your code, if you want to alert the `"Hello World!"` string and you don't need the event arguments that come with the fired event, you can bind the first argument of the saySomething function to `"Hello World!"`:

```
var boundHandler = saySomething.bind(window, "Hello World!");
addLoadListener(boundHandler);
```

**Edit**: Function.prototype.bind creates a new function where `this` and all of the arguments of the new function can be 'bound' to specific values. It's important to note that bind creates a new function and the original one is preserved. You can create as many bound versions of the original as you want.

If you call `boundHandler("something else")` or `boundHandler()`, `"Hello World!"` will still be alerted instead of the new text. That is why the event handling code later works.

If you create a bound function in this way:

```
function alertThis() { alert(this); }
var boundFn = alertThis.bind("my new this");

alertThis() // "[object Window]" is alerted
boundFn() // "my new this" is alerted
```

Here's more info about Function.prototype.bind: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind.

Comment: The purpose of my code is just testing and better understanding the JavaScript behavior. Can you please clarify what tha line exactly does? `saySomething.bind(window, "Hello World!");` . Thanks

Comment: Sure, I edited my answer to include more info. I hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, I am not sure I understand the use of `window` as `this` value. I red the link you provided and still dont really get what is going on. Thanks agian.

Comment: @slevin It's unfortunate that my attempt to help you actually confused you. Let me try to rectify that. In the body of the `saySomething` function, as you have defined it, `this` is the `window` object. `bind()` creates a new function and its first argument defines the `this` in the new function. I bound it to the `window` object to preserve the `this` of the original in a way. You can use `saySomething.bind(null)` without issues (`this` will be `null`) since you are not using `this` in the `saySomething` function.

Comment: aha, yes, makes sense now, using `null` or `undefined`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function saySomething(message)
  {
 alert(message);
 }

 saySomething('Hello world!');

function addLoadListener(fn){
  window.addEventListener('load', fn, false);
alert("the previous alert came from onload");
}

 addLoadListener( function() { saySomething('Hello world!') });


 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When "load" event happens it calls your function in this way: "saySomething(event)" - first argument is an event object. Not a string.

So you must change something in your code. For example:

```
function saySomething(message)
{
    var msg = typeof message != 'string' ? 'Hello world!' : message; //setting default message
    alert(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you add this function as an event listener. The first argument of an event listener function is an event object. This is why you're getting `[object Event]`.

You can bind your message to the context object. This is one way of solving your problem:

```
function saySomething(message) {
    alert(message);
}

function saySomethingListener(message) {
    saySomething(this.message);
}

saySomething('Hello world!');

function addLoadListener(fn) {
    window.addEventListener('load', fn.bind({message: 'Hello world!'}), false);
    alert("the previous alert came from onload");
}

addLoadListener(saySomethingListener);
```